# Does OKTA only supports OAuth token based access for REST APIs?

Tags: okta

I have written REST APIs. I have users in OKTA. Does OKTA only supports OAuth token based access for REST APIs or for my REST APIs I can also use some other authentication mechanisms as well to authenticate users to APIs??

Answer (score 0):

As it's your API you can protect it with whatever your want :) Some forms can be a static API token which a user would need to send you in an authorization header, or something else.

But as you have your users in Okta, it would make sense to go with a standard mechanisms like OAuth protection, where your app is registered with Okta as an OAuth service for which users would need to get an access token. Then you would ask that token to be sent in a standard `Authorization: Bearer xxxxx` header for it to be validated by any solid JWT verification library.